# Tkinter: global name not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add items to the listbox, but every time I try it, it's saying that the global name "title_input" is not defined. I don't understand why this doesn't work, because the last one that I did with this exact same structure didn't give me that error. I'm new to this, and the other tutorials and questions I read about global name errors didn't make sense to me. Thanks for the help!

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()
    self.list = Listbox(self, selectmode=BROWSE)
    self.list.grid(row = 1, column = 4, rowspan = 10, columnspan = 3, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

def create_widgets(self):
    #setlist box - may not stay text box?
    self.setlist = Text(self, height = 14, width = 25)
    self.setlist.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 10, columnspan = 3, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.setlistLabel = Label(self, text = "SetList")
    self.setlistLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    #Library label
    self.libraryLabel = Label(self, text = "Library")
    self.libraryLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady y = 5)

    #Library button/input

    self.add_title = Button(self, text = "Add Title", command = self.add_item)
    self.add_title.grid(row = 16, column = 5, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    self.title_input = Entry(self)
    self.title_input.grid(row = 16, column = 4, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

def add_item(self):
    list.insert(END, title_input.get())

def get_list(event):
    index = list.curselection()[0]
    seltext = list.get(index)
    setlist.insert(0, seltext)

root = Tk()
root.title("SetList Creator")
root.geometry("500x500")

app = Application (root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Missing `self.` in `list.insert(END, title_input.get())`...

Comment: So it should be: self.list.insert(END, title_input.get())?

Thanks! I put that in...still getting the global name error though

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: @IsaacAsimov almost, you were missing `self` twice in that line, should be `self.list.insert(END, self.title_input.get())`. Also, you should add `self.` to `seltext` and `list` in your `get_list()` function. Basically, everything that you define as `self.something` should be referenced as `self.something` everywhere else too.

Comment: @Julien Spronck...sorry, I'm not sure what that means. Like I said, I'm very new to this.

Comment: @fhdrsdg thank you, that makes sense. The tutorial I was looking at didn't use the "create widgets" thing that my professor said to use, so I think translating the tutorial into the format I'm supposed to do was what threw me off. Thanks!

Comment: I was asking you to post the full error message (traceback) with error name, error type, line numbers, ... anyway, looks like other people figured it out

Comment: @IsaacAsimov I think you would benefit from reading up on [Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

`title_input` is defined in your instance namespace but it is not defined in your global namespace. When you reference an unqualified `title_input` in your class method `add_item`, Python looks for `title_input` in the global namespace. When it doesn't find it there it gives you that error. Adding the `self` qualifier, `self.title_input`, to indicate that you wish to reference `title_input` in the instance namespace, will resolve the error.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. This might be a dumb question, but where would I put it if I wanted it to be in the global namespace? Would it go under the __init__ section or would it just go in the application and line up with the definitions? (I'm not going to make it global, I'll fix it by using the self qualifier, I'm just trying to make sure I understand the error)